# Different ways to integrate web phone/softphone/VOIP in asp.net web site

Tags: asp.net, voip, ozeki

I am planning to integrate a web phone/softphone in my ASP.Net web site. My idea is to provide an interface on my web page by which user can start a VOIP call to a pre-defined number.
Since I am new to VOIP/SIP domain I am not able to google exactly what I need or from where should I start. What I understand so far is there are open source SIP libraries and some licensed SDKs as well. Also there are some off the shelf client side plugins available which we can embed in the web site.

I am looking for various solutions and also open for paid SDK or client side plugin.  So far I have read about Ozeki C# SDK, Mizu plugin and Zoiper plugin.
Can someone help me understand following:
1.  From implementation point of view what we will be the difference between using open source SIP libraries vs paid SDKs like Ozeki vs readymade plugins like Mizu or Zoiper

2. Which are other options available to implement this?
3. From a reliability perspective which SDK or library is best suited?

Thanks
Amey

Answer (score 0):

Other options: any softphone that can register protocol handler - if you have control over webpage content and can insert "callto" or similar links into it. If you do not have control over webpage - add Telify plugin for firefox to replace text that looks like phone number with equivalent link.